# I have problem in saying Gerunds in German, please help :(

Tags: gerund

I have problem with translating English gerund to German :(

I get confused and lost .... :(

I do not why I can not get this structure correctly ...

some examples, how to say?

**1) "after leaving, she suffered very much"**

1a) "Nach der Abreise, sie hat viel gelitten"

1b) "Nach abzureisen, sie hat viel gelitten"

1c) "Nach abreisen zu haben, sie hat viel gelitten"

**2) "after saying something, you should wait for the response"**

2a) "Nach etwas zu sagen, du musst auf die Antwort warten"

2b) "Nach dem Sagen des (von) etwas, du musst auf die Antwort warten"

**3) "by buying that, I wanted to make you happy"**

3a) "indem das zu kaufen, wollte ich sie erfreuen"

3b) "durch den Kauf von dem, wollte ich sie refrauen"

Comment: Looks like homework ? Modern German knows no gerunds. Try switching the parts before and after the comma when translating from English to German. Exaple 1: "Sie hat viel gelitten nach der Abreise". Infinitive with "zu" makes little sense here, though it is not impossible to express nuances "Abzureisen ließ sie leiden". German can be cool. Another hint: to avoid confusion with conditional clauses "Wollte ich sie erfreuen ..." (If i wanted to make her happy) switch to a defintive form "Ich wollte sie erfreuen durch den ....".

Comment: I'm afraid, there is no "one-fits-all"-solution for translating English gerunds, since this structure doesn't exist in standard German...

Comment: @a_donda The given translations seem to be different versions of OP's attempts to solve this. They don't look like textbook solutions to me...

Comment: Yes, there is no cookbook recipe and there are several forms to express the matter in German. My first reamrk is only a hint, other solutions are possible.

Comment: None of the proposed solutions is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Nach der Abreise hat sie viel gelitten.

In German it is a normal sentence. Typical German verbal bracket.

> 2) Nachdem Du etwas gesagt hast, solltest Du auf eine Antwort warten.

First subordinate clause then main clause. As this seems to be a general advise I switched the defined artive to an undefined.

> 3) Weil ich Dich glücklich machen wollte, habe ich das für Dich gekauft.

"Erfreuen" is a bit outdated and sounds very formal. Don't use "beglücken", because this could easily put in a sexual context. "by doing this, I want to achieve that"-constructions can be turned into "weil"-constructions, but the weil has to be placed at the other part of the constucktion.

Comment: Zu 2: Hört sich falsch an. Muß es nicht heißen "Nachdem du etwas gesagt hast, solltest du auf eine Antwort warten" ?

Comment: Stimmt. Verschrieben

Comment: @NiklasE. Zum Präsenz "warten" das Perfekt "gesagt hast", stimmt's ? Das Präteritum verwirrt mich etwas ...

Comment: @a_donda Tatsächlich hört sich das nicht nur falsch an, es ist auch falsch. "solltest" ist Konjunktiv II Präsens. Da im Nebensatz mit "nachdem" eine zeitliche Abfolge indiziert wird, muss der Nebensatz auch die dazu passende Zeitform haben. Für Präsens wäre das Perfekt  (für Präteritum das PQP und für Futur I das Futur II). Also "gesagt hast" statt "sagst".  (Edit: Entschuldige, ich hab da was vertaucht.)